# Plotting line graph in different color from specific date

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am doing a forecast for the dataset when plotting I want to draw forecast values from a specific date in a different color in python.

I want like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could create a boolean array to tell which part to draw.

Here is an example supposing you are using pandas dates. When `<=` and `>=` are used with a date that is part of the x-axis, the line will continue. If not, the line will have a small interruption.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

t = pd.date_range('2015', '2021', freq='M')
sales = np.random.normal(100, 500, len(t) ).cumsum() + 10000

past = t <= '2020-02-29'
future = t >= '2020-02-29'
plt.plot(t[past], sales[past], color='dodgerblue')
plt.plot(t[future], sales[future], color='crimson')
plt.fill_between(t[future], sales[future] - 1000, sales[future] + 1000, color='crimson', alpha=0.3)
plt.ylabel('sales')

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]